# xampp not working on localhost(127.0.0.1) but works on(192.168.X.X)

Tags: xampp

Im running xampp-vm on macOS Catalina. Site loads fine on the provided ip by xampp (192.168.X.X/project_name) but it does not work on localhost (localhost/project_name). Is this normal or is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to check 'Network' tab to edit the mapping like:

```
localhost:8080 -> 80
```

to

```
localhost:80 -> 80
```

[image]

Image from the FAQ of Xampp: 
https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_stackman.html

Answer (score 0):

Put your projects in different folder. Assign for each project a different domain.

Configure Apache with different hosts.
You can follow the following video about [how to setup PHP environment using XAMPP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9hbSL4ctMw). The last part contains vhosts configuration